# What are all the "about:" pages, in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

I know `about:blank` will give you a blank page in Internet Explorer (and just about any other browser) and many of the error pages have URLs starting with just `about:` as well.  Are there any other pages of informational or diagnostic value that have similar addresses?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easiest way to find this info is from the [about: URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About:_URI_scheme) Wikipedia entry.

Note that on Windows Internet Explorer's `about:` addresses are configurable. It is therefore possible that some of the listed addresses will not work on a particular computer

There's a list of [common about: addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About:_URI_scheme#Common_about:_addresses) and a list of those [for Internet Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About:_URI_scheme#Internet_Explorer-specific_about:_addresses):

> **about:home**
>   Displays the user's home page.
>
> **about:blank**
>   Displays the blank page.
>
> **about:desktopitemnavigationfailure**
>   Displays "navigation cancelled" page.
>
> **about:navigationcanceled**
>   Displays "navigation cancelled" page.
>
> **about:navigationfailure**
>   Displays "navigation cancelled" page.
>
> **about:noadd-ons** (IE7+)
>   Displays information page when add-ons are disabled.
>
> **about:noadd-onsinfo** (IE7+)
>   Displays information page about the effects when you use add-ons.
>
> **about:offlineinformation**
>   Informs the user that the current page can not be viewed off line.
>
> **about:postnotcached**
>   Informs the user that to refresh the current page, information entered in a form will have to be re-posted.
>
> **about:securityrisk**
>   Informs the user not to browse with the current security settings because they may be harmful to the computer.
>
> **about:tabs** (IE7+)
>   Informs the user about tabbed browsing. It is also loaded when a new tab is created if the "Open home page for new tabs instead of a blank page" setting is enabled
>
> **about:inprivate** (IE8+)
>   Informs the user about InPrivate Browsing. It is loaded when InPrivate Browsing is initiated.

And one from the common list:

> **about:mozilla** (only before XP SP2)
>   The Windows version of IE showed a blank HTML document with blue background color. Possibly a joke reference to the "Blue Screen of Death". Removed in Windows XP SP2 but it can still be shown by typing "res://mshtml.dll/about.moz" instead

Comment: How do I configure the about urls in IE.  Mine have been hijacked by the delta-homes.com malicious software.

Comment: Don't know I'm afraid, probably worth asking a new question about.